# Find all similar values in an array and group together into a new array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

The problem: I have an array of objects, where the object has an x value. Each object also needs a y value, to be plotted on a Scatterplot. The y value needs to be a number between a min height(.3) and a max height(.6), and be evenly spaced based on the number of equal x values.

For example, if I have an array of objects where [(x=3)(x=4)(x=3)(x=4)(x=5)(x=3)], after iterating through the array I should have a new array of objects that looks like this: [(x=3, y=.3)(x=3, y=.45)(x=4, y=.6)(x=4, y=.3)(x=4, y=.6)(x=5, y=.45)].

The Question: What is the best way to accomplish this performance wise? Are there any packages out there that will help me iterate through the array.

Currently I've created a nested forEach loop, but the code for this is long and feels dirty to me. Any suggestions would be great :)

This is in an angular 4 project (typescript).

Comment: may be newArray = array.map(item=> item.y = some logic)

Comment: `[(x=3)(x=4)(x=3)(x=4)(x=5)(x=3)]` what's this notation anyway? Is it an array containing objects or arrays?

Comment: Just something I wrote up real quick, it's an array containing many objects (The objects have all sorts of user information in them other than just the x). so [] is the overall array, and () is each object

Comment: array.map(item => item.y) gives me how to give each y a value, but the value needs to be based on the count of objects that have the same x. Sometimes this will be 100 sometimes it will be 1.

Comment: Your input has 3 items with x=3 and 2 items with x=4 yet the output has the opposite.  Is this intentional?  I’m trying to understand your math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need the `map` function:

Check documantation at https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

With `map` you can transform you array into a new array, this way:

```js
var array = [{"x" : 3}, {"x" : 4}, {"x": 5}, {"x" : 3}];
var counter = 1;
    
var newArray = array.map(object => {
    
   var calculatedY = counter;
   counter++;
   //just an example, you have to calculate your y based on your conditions
    
   return { x : object.x, y : calculatedY }
})
    
console.log(newArray);
```